# Watching log4net log file with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, filesystemwatcher

I've created simple WPF control to monitor changes in log file. I used FileSystemWatcher to watch specific file. My configuration:

```
Directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(logFileFullPath);
Filter = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(logFileFullPath);
NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size);
EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

The problem is that changes are displayed only after refreshing the directory manually or opening log file.

I use RollingFileAppender in my log4net configuration so changes should be written immediately.

The question is: why dosn't it work and how to make it work?

**EDIT :**

Also when I update manually other monitored file the watcher works fine. So it must be some log4net issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally come up with solution. The problem had little to do with FileSystemWatcher. My log4net configuration was lacking the line:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

It's still quite interesting as I had no problem with opening log file from text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"logFileDirectoryPath");     
 watcher.Filter = "LogFileNameWithExtension";
 watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
 watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
```

`Changed Event`

```
 private void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
 {
   //Do Something
 }
```

Comment: Just create a temp file @ the same location with the same file name as Log4Net file and manually update the file and see if its notified

Comment: Also make sure that you are not creating the FileSystemWatcher instance within Using block.

Comment: Even when I only open the file, the event is fired. It's confusing.